# angularjs site works only with developer tools is open

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I have develop a web site using angular.
My surprise is when I access the site in Chrome without the inspector.

The page seems be frozen. nothing works.

Comment: Only fails in big resolutions, in my laptop works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about the screen resolution. Not about the chrome inspector.
When the chrome inspector was down, so the screen get bigger and the problem arises.